# Reactnative $JAVA_HOME path error

Tags: android, react-native, java-home

```
zzz@zzz-PC ~/AndroidStudioProjects/Example $ react-native run-android
Scanning 555 folders for symlinks in /home/zzz/AndroidStudioProjects/Example/node_modules (16ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Anyone can tell what's the problem, after I've run "react-native run-android" command. I've changed my JAVA_HOME path in /etc/environment, it still failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be pointing to a jdk, currently you are pointing to a JVM. Go [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and download the appropriate jdk and install it. Then switch your `JAVA_HOME` variable to the new path to the jdk.

Comment: This is my java jdk version, is it the correct one?
`openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)`

Comment: Yeah that seems like the right jdk. Your javahome should now be the path to your newly installed jdk. Mine is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101`  Yours may look slightly different but it will likely be something like that.